# problems while configuring accumulo

Tags: accumulo

In my system Hadoop and zookeeper working properly. Now I have just configured Accumulo.But when i am going to initialize Accumulo by

**accumulo init**

it is showing following errors.

---

```
[root@hydDev32 bin]# ./accumulo init

Uncaught exception: Provider com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl not found
javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl not found
        at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.accumulo.start.classloader.AccumuloClassLoader.getAccumuloString(AccumuloClassLoader.java:307)
        at org.apache.accumulo.start.classloader.AccumuloClassLoader.getAccumuloClasspathStrings(AccumuloClassLoader.java:291)
        at org.apache.accumulo.start.classloader.AccumuloClassLoader.findAccumuloURLs(AccumuloClassLoader.java:217)
        at org.apache.accumulo.start.classloader.AccumuloClassLoader.getAccumuloClassLoader(AccumuloClassLoader.java:375)
        at org.apache.accumulo.start.classloader.AccumuloClassLoader.getClassLoader(AccumuloClassLoader.java:393)
        at org.apache.accumulo.start.Main.main(Main.java:39)




[root@hydDev32 bin]#
```

---

can anybody help me to solve this problem...
??

Comment: I solved this problem by reinstall java into my machine.I forgot to mention my answer here.Anyhow thanks a lot to all and special thanks to #ohshazbot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just ran into this exact same problem, and it turned out that I had a bad `JAVA_HOME` set in my environment. Once I cleared that, the `JAVA_HOME` setting in `accumulo-env.sh` took over and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment to ask for further information, so this may be a shot in the dark. But com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl is not being found. This should be included in rt.jar (classes.jar in OSX), which is part of the java runtime. So I would look into the version of java you are using.

Also, if I am mistaken, can you please clarify with the version of Accumulo, Hadoop, and Java.

Comment: thank you for the reply,..</br>my machine java -version = 1.6.0
accumulo -ver = 1.4.0
hadoop -ver   = 0.20.2
zookeeper -ver    = 3.3.3

Comment: What OS and what java 1.6.0 release is it? And is it the Sun/oracle java or is it openjdk?

Comment: OS -- Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.3 (Tikanga)//// Java -- Sun/oracle

Comment: Did you check your rt.jar to see if DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl was there?

Comment: I have just checked now.The DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl class is not there in that jar file.So I have downloaded a jar file(which contains that class) and copied in to java-lib.But it still showing the same error.

Comment: So, this is stemming from DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance() ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#newInstance%28%29 ). It has an ordered list for how it grabs the appropriate DocumentBuilder, defined in the javadoc. I would go through that and make sure you're not setting that in there to a DocumentBuilder you don't have.